# Hyper-V Cluster - Shared Disk replication througth WMI

Tags: c#

Lo primero dar las gracias por este maravilloso foro, me ha salvado más de 100.

Para introducir un poco el problema que tengo, empezaré explicando la infraestructura en la que radica el error.

Tenemos un cliente que actualmente cuenta con 4 host(s) de Hyper-V, en Failover Cluster, con Windows Server 2016.

Microsoft dice en las notas de release que la replicación de los shared disk está solo disponible a través de la clase `Msvm_ReplicationCollectionService` de WMI, por lo que nos hemos puesto manos a la obra:

[Clase `Msvm_CollectionReplicationService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt167787(v=vs.85).aspx)

Hemos implementado la clase según el antiguo modelo de replicación de VMs, en el scope `root/virtualization/v2`, el nuevo que usamos es el `root/HyperVCluster/v2`, pero no hay ningún modelo a seguir.

Como primer paso, intentamos crear un relationship usando el método `CreateReplicationRelationship`. La llamada al método falla diciendo:

> The method call failed.

sin dar más detalles.

¿Tenéis alguna ligera idea de que sucede?  ¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer más debug al WMI?

TRAZAS DE ERROR:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: The method
>   call failed.  at
>   Microsoft.Samples.HyperV.Common.WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput(ManagementBaseObject
>   outputParameters, ManagementScope scope, Boolean throwIfFailed,
>   Boolean printErrors) in
>   C:\Users\isarria\Documents\Replica\cs\WmiUtilities.cs:line 136    at
>   Microsoft.Samples.HyperV.Common.WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput(ManagementBaseObject
>   outputParameters, ManagementScope scope) in
>   C:\Users\isarria\Documents\Replica\cs\WmiUtilities.cs:line 59    at
>   Microsoft.Samples.HyperV.Replica.ManageReplication.CreateReplicationRelationship(String
>   name, String name2, String CollectionID, String recoveryServerName) in
>   C:\Users\isarria\Documents\Replica\cs\ManageReplication.cs:line 85
>   at Microsoft.Samples.HyperV.Replica.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\isarria\Documents\Replica\cs\Program.cs:line 107

CÓDIGO ACTUAL:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables replication for a collection of virtual machines to a specified DRserver using 
    /// integrated authentication.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name of VM 1</param>
    /// <param name="name2">Name of VM 2</param>
    /// <param name="CollectionID">CollectionID to enable replication.</param>
    /// <param name="recoveryServerName">The name of the recovery server.</param>
    internal static void
    CreateReplicationRelationship(
        string name,
        string name2,
        string CollectionID,
        string recoveryServerName)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\HyperVCluster\v2");
        ManagementScope oldScope = new ManagementScope(@"root\virtualization\v2");

        //
        // Retrieve the Msvm_VirtualSystemCollection.
        //
        using (ManagementObject vm = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachine(name, oldScope))
        {
            using (ManagementObject vm2 = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachine(name2, oldScope))
            {
                string vmPath = vm.Path.Path;
                string vmPath2 = vm2.Path.Path;
                using (ManagementObject collection = WmiUtilities.GetVMGroup(CollectionID, scope))
                {
                    using (ManagementObject replicationSettingData =
                        ReplicaUtilities.GetReplicationSettings(vm))
                    {
                        replicationSettingData["RecoveryConnectionPoint"] = recoveryServerName;
                        replicationSettingData["AuthenticationType"] = 1;
                        replicationSettingData["RecoveryServerPortNumber"] = 80;
                        replicationSettingData["CompressionEnabled"] = 1;

                        // Keep 24 recovery points.
                        replicationSettingData["RecoveryHistory"] = 24;

                        // Replicate changes after every 300 seconds.
                        replicationSettingData["ReplicationInterval"] = 300;

                        // Take VSS snapshot every one hour.
                        replicationSettingData["ApplicationConsistentSnapshotInterval"] = 1;

                        // Include all disks for replication.
                        replicationSettingData["IncludedDisks"] = WmiUtilities.GetVhdSettings(vm);
                        //replicationSettingData["IncludedDisks"] = WmiUtilities.GetVhdSettings(vm2);

                        Console.WriteLine(replicationSettingData["IncludedDisks"].ToString());

                        string settingDataEmbedded =
                            replicationSettingData.GetText(TextFormat.WmiDtd20);

                        using (ManagementObject replicationService =
                            ReplicaUtilities.GetVirtualMachineReplicationService(scope))
                        {
                            using (ManagementBaseObject inParams =
                                replicationService.GetMethodParameters("CreateReplicationRelationship"))
                            {
                                inParams["Collection"] = collection;
                                inParams["CollectionReplicationSettingData"] = settingDataEmbedded;

                                using (ManagementBaseObject outParams =
                                    replicationService.InvokeMethod("CreateReplicationRelationship",
                                        inParams,
                                        null))
                                {
                                    WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput(outParams, scope);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                            "Replication is successfully enabled for vmGroup: \"{0}\"", CollectionID));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Msvm_VirtualSystemCollection instance that matches the requested VMGroup name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CollectionID">The CollectionID to retrieve the path for.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns>The Msvm_VirtualSystemCollection instance.</returns>
    public static ManagementObject
    GetVMGroup(
        string CollectionID,
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        return GetCollectionObject(CollectionID, "Msvm_VirtualSystemCollection", scope);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Msvm_ComputerSystem instance that matches the requested virtual machine name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the virtual machine to retrieve the path for.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns>The Msvm_ComputerSystem instance.</returns>
    public static ManagementObject
    GetVirtualMachine(
        string name,
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        return GetVmObject(name, "Msvm_ComputerSystem", scope);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the first virtual machine object of the given class with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the virtual machine to retrieve the path for.</param>
    /// <param name="className">The class of virtual machine to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns>The instance representing the virtual machine.</returns>
    private static ManagementObject
    GetVmObject(
        string name,
        string className,
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        string vmQueryWql = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE ElementName=\"{1}\"", className, name);

        SelectQuery vmQuery = new SelectQuery(vmQueryWql);

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, vmQuery))
        using (ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmSearcher.Get())
        {
            if (vmCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ManagementException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "No {0} could be found with name \"{1}\"",
                    className,
                    name));
            }

            //
            // If multiple virtual machines exist with the requested name, return the first 
            // one.
            //
            ManagementObject vm = GetFirstObjectFromCollection(vmCollection);

            return vm;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the replication settings object for a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="systemCollection">The Msvm_VirtualSystemCollection mache object.</param>
    /// <returns>The replication settings object.</returns>
    internal static ManagementObject
    GetReplicationSettings(
        ManagementObject systemCollection)
    {
        using (ManagementObjectCollection settingsCollection =
                systemCollection.GetRelated("Msvm_ReplicationSettingData"))
        {
            ManagementObject replicationSettings = 
                WmiUtilities.GetFirstObjectFromCollection(settingsCollection);

            return replicationSettings;
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the first virtual machine object of the given class with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param CollectionID="CollectionID">The name of the virtual machine to retrieve the path for.</param>
    /// <param name="className">The class of virtual machine to search for.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns>The instance representing the virtual machine.</returns>
    private static ManagementObject
    GetCollectionObject(
        string CollectionID,
        string className,
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        string vmQueryWql = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE CollectionID=\"{1}\"", className, CollectionID);

        SelectQuery vmQuery = new SelectQuery(vmQueryWql);

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, vmQuery))
        using (ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmSearcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementObject CollectionObject = null;
            if (vmCollection.Count == 1)
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in vmCollection)
                {
                    CollectionObject = managementObject; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ManagementException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "No {0} could be found with ID \"{1}\"",
                    className,
                    CollectionID));
            }
            return CollectionObject;
        }

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the virtual system replication service.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scope">The scope to use when connecting to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns>The collection virtual machine replication service.</returns>
    public static ManagementObject
    GetVirtualMachineReplicationService(
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        ManagementScope scope2 = new ManagementScope(@"root\HyperVCluster\v2");
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Msvm_CollectionReplicationService");

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher queryExecute = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope2, query))
        using (ManagementObjectCollection serviceCollection = queryExecute.Get())
        {
            if (serviceCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ManagementException("Cannot find the collection replication service object. " +
                    "Please check that the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service is running.");
            }

            return WmiUtilities.GetFirstObjectFromCollection(serviceCollection);
        }
    }
```

@Pikoh: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. El método "ValidateOutput" lo único que hace es responder con la información de la llamada al WMI. Pego el código a continuación.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the output parameters of a method call and prints errors, if any.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputParameters">The output parameters of a WMI method call.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if successful and not firing an alert; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public static bool
    ValidateOutput(
        ManagementBaseObject outputParameters,
        ManagementScope scope)
    {
        return ValidateOutput(outputParameters, scope, true, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the output parameters of a method call and prints errors, if any.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputParameters">The output parameters of a WMI method call.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The ManagementScope to use to connect to WMI.</param>
    /// <param name="throwIfFailed"> If true, the method throws on failure.</param>
    /// <param name="printErrors">If true, Msvm_Error messages are displayed.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if successful and not firing an alert; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public static bool
    ValidateOutput(
        ManagementBaseObject outputParameters,
        ManagementScope scope,
        bool throwIfFailed,
        bool printErrors)
    {
        bool succeeded = true;
        string errorMessage = "The method call failed.";

        if ((uint)outputParameters["ReturnValue"] == 4096)
        {
            //
            // The method invoked an asynchronous operation. Get the Job object
            // and wait for it to complete. Then we can check its result.
            //

            using (ManagementObject job = new ManagementObject((string)outputParameters["Job"]))
            {
                job.Scope = scope;

                while (!IsJobComplete(job["JobState"]))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                    // 
                    // ManagementObjects are offline objects. Call Get() on the object to have its
                    // current property state.
                    //
                    job.Get();
                }

                if (!IsJobSuccessful(job["JobState"]))
                {
                    succeeded = false;

                    //
                    // In some cases the Job object can contain helpful information about
                    // why the method call failed. If it did contain such information,
                    // use it instead of a generic message.
                    //
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)job["ErrorDescription"]))
                    {
                        errorMessage = (string)job["ErrorDescription"];
                    }

                    if (printErrors)
                    {
                        PrintMsvmErrors(job);
                    }

                    if (throwIfFailed)
                    {
                        throw new ManagementException(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((uint)outputParameters["ReturnValue"] != 0)
        {
            succeeded = false;

            if (throwIfFailed)
            {
                throw new ManagementException(errorMessage);
            }
        }

        return succeeded;
    }
```

Comment: Parece complejo que puedas recibir ayuda en un tema tan especializado (yo en mi caso por ejemplo nunca he trabajado en ese área). Pero, por intentar darte alguna idea, el error indica que el problema es el método `WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput`. Lo que yo haría es revisar qué parámetros le estás enviando al método, y si es posible depurar paso a paso entrando en dicho método. También echaría un ojo a la `InnerException` que puede que te de más información sobre la excepción. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so] :)